# How can I develop a color filter in Unity that adjusts green shades to be more distinguishable for individuals?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I currently have created a lot of objects with materials (that have different colors for different objects). In my application, I want to show in the left side, the objects with their original color, and in the right, duplicate those objects, and add some filter, so that they will be different after the filtering.

ChatGPT suggested for me using Shader, and adding my filter to there, and apply it to material, and then apply this material to the object. However, the objects have colors because I already applied materials (for example with green color), in order to apply the material with the shader I have to remove the material with the color.

So, basically, I want to apply filtering on the top of those different materials (so it will change the base color of the material). What I need to do for that?

So, basically, I want to apply filtering on the top of those different materials (so it will change the base color of the material). What I need to do for that?